# How to get Wi-Fi Information Elements in Windows Native Wifi

Tags: winapi, wifi, beacon

The Windows [Native Wifi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/nativewifi/about-the-native-wifi-api) documentation mentions 802.11 Information Elements (IEs) from Beacon or Probe Response frames are available through the [WLAN_BSS_ENTRY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/ns-wlanapi-wlan_bss_entry) structure, specifically, through its ulIeOffset and ulIeSize members, which define an area of memory that contains the IE data blob. I've been unsuccessful with retrieving IEs using these two variables.

I get multiple valid WLAN_BSS_ENTRY structures through [GetAvailableNetworkList()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlangetavailablenetworklist) (correctly populated with 802.11 network information - SSID, BSSID, etc.) - ulIeOffset and ulIeSize values make sense too, but I get read exception when trying to access that memory area.

My test platform is Windows 10 with all updates as of this post date, latest Visual Studio Community edition, and I wrote a simple console application that prints all WLAN_BSS_ENTRY fields (successful), and the IE data blob (unsuccessful). C++ code related to scan is shown below. Any insight appreciated.

```
// retrieve scanned networks
dwResult = WlanGetNetworkBssList(hClient, &pIfList->InterfaceInfo[0].InterfaceGuid,
        NULL, dot11_BSS_type_any, false, NULL, &pBssList);
if (dwResult == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < pBssList->dwNumberOfItems; i++) {
        const WLAN_BSS_ENTRY bssEntry = pBssList->wlanBssEntries[i];
        std::cout << "SSID: " << bssEntry.dot11Ssid.ucSSID << std::endl;
        std::cout << "RSSI: " << bssEntry.lRssi << " dBm" << std::endl;
        // print bunch of other bssEntry fields, all valid
        std::cout << "IE buffer offset: " << bssEntry.ulIeOffset << std::endl;
        std::cout << "IE buffer size: " << bssEntry.ulIeSize << std::endl;
        // --> IE retrieval below doesn't work (throws read exception) <--
        const PBYTE ieBuffer = (const PBYTE)((PBYTE)(&bssEntry) + bssEntry.ulIeOffset);
        for (DWORD j = 0; j < bssEntry.ulIeSize; j++) {
           printf("%02X ", ieBuffer[j]);
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    WlanFreeMemory(pBssList);
}
```

Comment: Have a look wlsample's [PrintBssInfo](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/ac06e54a15e9a62443e400fffff190fb978ea586/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/wlan/autoconfig/wlsample.cpp#L568).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this code:

```
const WLAN_BSS_ENTRY bssEntry = pBssList->wlanBssEntries[i];
```

makes a copy of the WLAN_BSS_ENTRY structure, so it's address points to another place in memory. You want to keep everything as pointers:

```
WlanGetNetworkBssList(hClient, &pIfList->InterfaceInfo[0].InterfaceGuid, NULL, dot11_BSS_type_any, false, NULL, &pBssList);
for (DWORD i = 0; i < pBssList->dwNumberOfItems; i++) {

    // use the original pointer
    PWLAN_BSS_ENTRY bssEntry = &pBssList->wlanBssEntries[i]

    std::cout << "SSID: " << bssEntry->dot11Ssid.ucSSID << std::endl;
    std::cout << "RSSI: " << bssEntry->lRssi << " dBm" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "IE buffer offset: " << bssEntry->ulIeOffset << std::endl;
    std::cout << "IE buffer size: " << bssEntry->ulIeSize << std::endl;

    PBYTE ieBuffer = (PBYTE)bssEntry + bssEntry->ulIeOffset;
    for (DWORD j = 0; j < bssEntry->ulIeSize; j++) {
        printf("%02X ", ieBuffer[j]);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
WlanFreeMemory(pBssList);
```